# Can't get gmail one click confirm action button working

Tags: javascript, gmail, schema.org, google-schemas

I am following the guidelines as described here
https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/one-click-action

But It's just wont appear for me. As described [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/testing-your-schema)

> Self testing
>
> You can easily test if your markup is working correctly end-to-end by
>   sending emails with schemas to your Gmail account. All emails where
>   the sender and the recipient are the same account ignore the
>   registration requirements and can be used for self-testing.

I am using my same gmail address in both to and from address like below

```
GradeCard gc = new GradeCard("105106265", "BTS");
var m = new UserMailer().ConfirmSubscription("Shashwat", "user@email.com", new WatchListEmail() { fullName = "from Model", gc = gc });

Response.Write(m.Body);

var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@email.com", "xxxxx"),
    EnableSsl = true
};

client.Send(m);
```

HTML of generated mail is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
    <div style="width: 600px; margin: auto; font-family: 'Segoe UI';">
        <h1 style="font-weight:lighter; border-bottom:1px solid #808080; padding:5px 0;">example.com</h1>
        <h3 style="font-weight:lighter;">Action Required. Confirm your subscription for EN abc</h3>
        <p>
            Dear <b>abc</b>
        </p>
        <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "description": "Action Required. Confirm your subscription for EN 105106265",
  "action": {
    "@type": "ConfirmAction",
    "name": "Add to watchlist",
    "handler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "http://www.myignou.com?a=1&b=2"
    }
  }
}
</script>

<p>As you requested, We have just added your subscription to the following detailed enrollment number</p>
<p>
    ...
</p>
<p>
    Click <a href="http://www.myignou.com?a=1&b=2">here to confirm</a>
</p>
<div style="margin:10px 0;">
    <p>
        Here is your most recent copy of grade card as on <b>05-09-2013 00:03:37</b><br />
        Changeset ID: xxx
    </p>

    <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center; border-collapse: collapse;">
        ....
    </table>
    <h3 style="font-weight: lighter;">Other previous changes</h3>
        <div style="padding: 10px">
            <h4 style="font-weight: lighter; margin: 0">Updated on 03-09-2013 15:15:20</h4>
            <div>Changeset ID: abc</div>
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 10px">
            <h4 style="font-weight: lighter; margin: 0">Updated on 03-09-2013 15:14:21</h4>
            <div>Changeset ID: xxx</div>
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding: 10px">
            <h4 style="font-weight: lighter; margin: 0">Updated on 03-09-2013 15:14:21</h4>
            <div>Changeset ID: abca</div>
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div style="padding: 10px; margin: 20px 0; background-color: #f2f0f0; font-size: 85%; color: #686868;">
            <b>&copy; 2013 myIGNOU.com</b><br />

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the email headers, I'd expect that no DKIM/SPF signature can be found, and that is required even for self-testing. Without the signature, anyone can spoof your email address and send you unwanted email with actions.

Comment: Thanks u for your response. As u had suggested in ur other answer. I successfully tested it with script.google.com. But is there a way to add DKIM/SPF signature when sending email from google account (gmail) ..?

Comment: DKIM uses a domain key so you need a Google Apps domain to do that

Comment: Yup, DKIM/SPF signature is required. You cannot test it, even with same sender and receiver email address. I am using ManDrilApp. Which is working. @RahulChaudhari

Answer (score 7):

**You have to be approved by Google first, in order for it to work.**

To do this:

1. Send your validated schema-containing email to a special google email address (use this tool: https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/) ... then:
2. Fill out the "Gmail Schema Whitelist Request" form that describes your website and what you intend to do with the one-click action. Here's the form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1&fbzx=-1177483801701354615